# How to solve $2f-f_u=g(v)$?

Tags: partial-differential-equations

> How to solve $2f-f_u=g(v)$, where $f=f(u,v)$ ?

somehow it is similiar to a case in ODE's (integrating factor method) but here we have more than $1$ variable and RHS is a function of $v$.

for example [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/229651/233857) ''After integration we get'', how did he integrate ?

Comment: Couldn't you divide by $f_u$, add $1$ and integrate with respect to $u$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fix some $v$. Then you have $f_u = 2f - g(v)$, which is a (very simple) linear ODE in $u$ (namely $y' = 2y - g$, where $g$ is a constant). Solve it and you get $f(u,v)$ for this particular $v$. But since $v$ was arbitrary, you get $f(u,v)$. The solution is $f(u,v) = \frac 1 2g(v) + c(v)e^{2u}$, where $c$ is some function depending on $v$.

Comment: Thanks, but in the link I gave did you see there, after integrating, we have also another function $A(v)$, so the solution should be  $f(u,v)=1/2g(v)+ce^{2u}+A(v)$, or not ?

Comment: The "constant" appearing here ($c$) should be a function of $v$, right?

Comment: Yes, exactly that, YoTengoUnLCD. I edited it.